# Mathematica Module versus With or Block - Guideline, rule of thumb for usage?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Leonid wrote in chapter iv of his book : "... Module, Block and With. These constructs are explained in detail in Mathematica Book and Mathematica Help, so I will say just a few words about them here. ..."

From what I have read ( been able to find ) I am still in the dark. For packaged functions I ( simply ) use Module, because it works and I know the construct. It may not be the best choice though. It is not entirely clear to me ( from the documentation ) when, where or why to use With ( or Block ).

#### Question. Is there a rule of thumb / guideline on when to use Module, With or Block ( for functions in packages )? Are there limitations compared to Module? The docs say that With is faster. I want to be able to defend my =choice= for Module ( or another construct ).

Comment: Similar question on MM.SE: [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A more practical difference between `Block` and `Module` can be seen here:

```
Module[{x}, x]
Block[{x}, x]
(*
-> x$1979
   x
*)
```

So if you wish to return eg `x`, you can use `Block`. For instance,

```
Plot[D[Sin[x], x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

does not work; to make it work, one could use

```
Plot[Block[{x}, D[Sin[x], x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

(of course this is not ideal, it is simply an example).

Another use is something like `Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1000},...]`, which temporarily changes `$RecursionLimit` (`Module` would not have worked as it renames `$RecursionLimit`).

One can also use `Block` to block evaluation of something, eg

```
Block[{Sin}, Sin[.5]] // Trace
(*
-> {Block[{Sin},Sin[0.5]],Sin[0.5],0.479426}
*)
```

ie, it returns `Sin[0.5]` which is only evaluated after the `Block` has finished executing. This is because `Sin` inside the `Block` is just a symbol, rather than the sine function. You could even do something like

```
Block[{Sin = Cos[#/4] &}, Sin[Pi]]
(*
-> 1/Sqrt[2]
*)
```

(use `Trace` to see how it works). So you can use `Block` to locally redefine built-in functions, too:

```
Block[{Plus = Times}, 3 + 2]
(*
-> 6
*)
```

Comment: Following your example I tried this. Clear[x]; x = 1; Module[{x}, x] - It returned with the ( for me ) unexpected result of x$114.

Comment: The example with $RecursionLimit is very useful.

Comment: Regarding your example with `Plot`.  I believe `Plot` has some heuristics to decide whether to evaluate its argument *before* a numerical value is substituted for `x` or only after.  The only difference your use of `Block` makes there is changing when `Plot` will evaluate its argument.  It doesn't illustrate how `Block` works.  You can verify this by including a `Print[x]` statement in `Plot`'s argument.  (Setting the undocumented `Evaluated` option to `False` in `Plot` doesn't appear to work.)

Comment: My point is that the problem with that `Plot` is evaluation of the argument.  The proper way to make it work is `Plot[Evaluate[...], ...]`.  The fact that wrapping the argument in `Block` also fixes it is merely accidental, and is due to `Plot`'s internal heuristics to decide about evaluation order.

Comment: @Szabolcs OK, could be. I do not dispute the `Evaluate` bit, that is why I said it is not ideal the way I show it here.

Comment: @Szabolcs so I tried `Plot[Block[{x}, Sow[x]; D[Sin[x], x]], {x, 0, 10}] // Reap` and `Block` does get evaluated every time. So your point is that the fact that evaluation does not occur isn't due to `Block`? I agree, but all I was trying to demonstrate is that the fact that `Block` does not rename `x` can be used in the way I showed (for cases where you can't just `Evaluate`; here it's overkill). Or did I miss your point?

Comment: @acl, I was not entirely correct in my assumptions, and now I'm a bit confused.  I assume that if `Plot` set a value to `x` *before* evaluating its argument, then `Block` doesn't help as we'd end up with something like `Block[{1}, D[Sin[1], 1]]`.  Some weirdness about scoping rules must be at work here ...  It's not at all clear to me *why* exactly this use of `Block` prevents the errors.

Comment: @ndroock1 what makes this unexpected? The idea is that `Module` renames its arguments, so they are unaffected by definitions outside the `Module` body

Comment: @acl. You are right. I confused myself. I thought it had touched x, but it didn't. Much is more clearer now.

Answer (score 32):

As you mentioned there are many things to consider and a detailed discussion is possible. But here are some rules of thumb that I apply the majority of the time:

`Module[{x}, ...]` is the safest and may be needed if either

1. There are existing definitions for x that you want to avoid breaking during the evaluation of the Module, or
2. There is existing code that relies on x being *undefined* (for example code like `Integrate[..., x]`).

Module is also the only choice for creating and returning a new symbol. In particular, Module is sometimes needed in advanced Dynamic programming for this reason.

If you are confident there aren't important existing definitions for x or any code relying on it being undefined, then `Block[{x}, ...]` is often faster. (Note that, in a project entirely coded by you, being confident of these conditions is a reasonable "encapsulation" standard that you may wish to enforce anyway, and so Block is often a sound choice in these situations.)

`With[{x = ...}, expr]` is the only scoping construct that injects the value of x inside `Hold[...]`. This is useful and important. `With` can be either faster or slower than Block depending on expr and the particular evaluation path that is taken. `With` is less flexible, however, since you can't change the definition of x inside expr.

Comment: +1 A nice summary! I have just two comments: first, if we agree that `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` are scoping constructs (which they are in some ways), they give another (non-equivalent) way of injecting inside held expressions.  Second, I would *not* use `Block` for simple encapsulation, unless its dynamic scoping functionality is fully needed - it is hard to be responsible for some parts of execution stack, especially  if you pass functions as parameters, where arbitrary code may be executed. Small speed improvements from using `Block` now may result in very subtle bugs later down the road.

Comment: That's a good point about encapsulation with Block not being safe when handling user supplied functions or expressions, since they may refer to Global` variables. In this case, Block can only be safe if it is within the private section of a package, that is, after a `Begin["\`Private\`"]` statement.

Comment: Isn't `Unique[]` another way to create and return a new symbol? `Module[{x},x]` produces something like `$x123` whereas `Unique[]` produces something like `$234`.

Comment: Yes Unique[] can also be used to create a new symbol. The advantage of Module[{x}...] over something like x=Unique[] is that you'll get the unique x used everywhere in e.g. Set statements like x=5. A statement like that won't work after x=Unique[]. You'd need gymnastics like Evaluate[x]=5.

Answer (score 13):

Andrew has already provided a very comprehensive answer. I would just summarize by noting that `Module` is for defining local *variables* that can be redefined within the scope of a function definition, while `With` is for defining local *constants*, which can't be. You also can't define a local constant based on the definition of another local constant you have set up in the same `With` statement, or have multiple symbols on the LHS of a definition. That is, the following does not work.

```
With[{{a,b}= OptionValue /@ {opt1,opt2} }, ...]
```

I tend to set up complicated function definitions with  `Module` enclosing a `With`. I set up all the local constants I can first inside the `With`, e.g. the `Length` of the data passed to the function, if I need that, then other local variables as needed. The reason is that `With` is a little faster of you genuinely do have constants not variables.

Comment: Actually, (at least in v7) you can't define local variables in terms of the other variables in `Module` either, at least at the definition stage, i.e. `Module[{a = 1, b = a}, b]` returns `a` while `Block[{a = 1, b = a}, b]` returns 1. Since the variables are immutable in `With`, there is no way around this, but in the body of `Module` you can set `b = a` and have it behave like `Block`.

Comment: I tend to use `With` in places I should use `Function`, to provide variable names. I do this to ensure pure functions behave a little better, but `Function` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @rcollyer: yes, I meant that I then define the local variable tha depends on the other one inside the body of `Module` and inside the enclosed `With`. Sorry if this wasn't clear. I used named constants in a `With` if I am going to use them more than once in a function definition. Otherwise pure functions are the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to mention the official documentation on the difference between `Block` and `Module` is available at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html.

Comment: Thank you. - I think you have indexed your files better than me. I depend on Google for most part.