# Multiple statements in mathematica function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wanted to know, how to evaluate multiple statements in a function in Mathematica.
E.g.

```
f[x_]:=x=x+5 and then return x^2
```

I know this much can be modified as `(x+5)^2` but originally I wanted to read data from the file in the function and print the result after doing some data manipulation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to group several commands and output the last use the semicolon (;) between them, like

```
f[y_]:=(x=y+5;x^2)
```

Just don't use a ; for the last statement.

If your set of commands grows bigger you might want to use scoping structures like [Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) or [Block](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html).

Comment: I think one should localize variables regardless of the program size, since programs do evolve and unlocalized variables are an invitation for trouble.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html) (short form `;`):

```
f[x_]:= (thing = x+5 ; thing^2)
```

The parentheses are necessary due to the very low precedence of `;`.

As Szabolcs called me on, you cannot write:

```
f[x_]:= (x = x+5 ; x^2)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8222227/618728) for an explanation and alternatives.

---

[Leonid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565518/leonid-shifrin), who you should listen to, says that `thing` should be localized.  I didn't do this above because I wanted to emphasize `CompoundExpression` as a specific fit for your "and then" construct.  As it is written, this will affect the global value of `thing` which may or may not be what you actually want to do.  If it is not, see both the answer linked above, and also:

- [Mathematica Module versus With or Block - Guideline, rule of thumb for usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6661393/618728)

Comment: Wow, 30 seconds!  I'll delete mine :)

Comment: But only if you correct the `x=x+5` bit either by using another variable or `HoldAll` or something that avoids obvious errors!

Comment: @Szabolcs oops!  Speed has is failings.

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. I wonder if Mr.Wizard has discovered the secret of time travel.

Comment: I think `thing` should be localized.

Comment: @Leonid please tell me if that addresses your concern.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it does, thanks. It is IMO ok to have the code like that exposed, as long as it is always stated what are the limitations and possible problems with  it, right next to it (don't get me wrong, I am mostly concerned with new users here)

Comment: @acl it looks like you're due for your silver tag badge.  Congrats!

Comment: @acl I'm done for the day unless something *really* tantalizing comes up, and I happen to be here.

Comment: @acl, congrats on the silver, and it is our goal to prevent our top users (myself included) from being able to answer anything without tripping over each other. That way, we can limit the number of badges handed out. Just remember, "we don't need no stinkin' badges!" (I apologize for the [pop-culture reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges).)

Comment: @rcollyer thanks! it would still have been nice to be able to answer a question once in a while, though!

Comment: @acl, I empathize with your plight. I hate being seconds away from posting an answer and having another one posted. A lot of times, though, I have better references (unless it is Leonid), so I leave my answer to compete with theirs.

Comment: @acl judging from the (lack of) votes for this answer, people may want to punish me for posting first, so posting your answer anyway gives them an outlet for votes. :^)

Comment: @Mr.W yes, I wondered why your answer here got no votes (I didn't vote for any of them, now that I think of it!). looks like the number of votes is roughly proportional to the length of the (initial) answer. I have noticed something like this before.

Answer (score 7):

Several people have mentioned already that you can use [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html):

```
f[x_] := (y=x+5; y^2)
```

However, if you use the same variable `x` in the expression as in the argument,

```
f[x_] := (x=x+5; x^2)
```

then you'll get errors when evaluating the function with a number.  This is because `:=` essentially defines a *replacement* of the pattern variables from the lhs, i.e. `f[1]` evaluates to the (incorrect) `(1 = 1+5; 1^2)`.

So, as Sjoerd said, use `Module` (or `Block` sometimes, but [this one has caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661393/mathematica-module-versus-with-or-block-guideline-rule-of-thumb-for-usage)!) to localize a function-variable:

```
f[x_] := Module[{y}, y=x+5; y^2]
```

Finally, if you need a function that modified its arguments, then you can set the attribute `HoldAll`:

```
Clear[addFive]    
SetAttributes[addFive, HoldAll]
addFive[x_] := (x=x+5)
```

Then use it as

```
a = 3;
addFive[a]
a
```

Comment: thanks a lot.
I think this will work. I feel that Mathematica Help is pathetic, they should make that more usable and userfriendly...other than that I like it.

Comment: @newGuy I find the Mathematica documentation excellent compared to most other programs I've seen.  Enter `tutorial/SequencesOfOperations` in the doc browser and click the Virtual Book button.